# time taken to decrypt data in mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption, aes, des

i am compairing the time taken to query records in mysql in 3 different ways for a coursework project.
i have set up 3 identical databases

1 not encrypted,
1 that using a trigger to AES ENCRYPT inserted data,
1 that using a trigger to DES ENCRYPT inserted data

used a single table with a user id & 6 VARBINARY columns for encrypted personal details like names and addresses (all encrypted with a single key).

after inserting 2000 rows the encrtption seems to be working correctly.
unfortunately the time taken to query and decrypt even all of the results is only taking 0.01 secconds so isnt noticable.

any suggestions on what would make the difference in time taken to retreive the data more noticable?

Comment: 2000 are too few  try inserting  20.000  or 200.000

Comment: represent your data better. It is totally confusing what your results are

Comment: using mockaroo.com to generate the data 100 rows at a time & combining into a single text document to pasting into the console. i suspected that i might need a larger ammount of data but this would take forever to put together 100 rows at a time.

Comment: But of course you ralize DES should not be used for new work, it is terrible insecure.

Comment: I hope you do not plan to use a symmetric encryption to protect sensitive data in a real life project.

Comment: @Shadow Wrong, there is nothing wrong or insecure with symmetric encryption, that is how data is encrypted.

Comment: have put together a long insert made up of (select concat(substring('abc.....', rand()*26+1,1)) and using to populate the table with random data. should be able to use 'insert from' to insert the data into the encrypted tables through the triggers to keep the data identical.  will try to put in a for/while loop rather than sitting all day pressing ctrl&V to populate